# How to use variables in list created by for loop into another for loop - R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have two lists, being `bufs` and `buffer_vals`. The list `buffer_vars` is a product of a for loop whereby the items of `bufs` are passed into, processed, and stored into variables that will be assigned to the list `buffer_vars`. When I apply the summary function on both lists, `bufs` outputs:

```
#summary(bufs)
   Length   Class  Mode   
[1,] 1      -none- numeric
[2,] 1      -none- numeric
[3,] 1      -none- numeric
[4,] 1      -none- numeric
[5,] 1      -none- numeric
```

while `buffer_vars` outputs:

```
#summary(buffer_vals)
      Length  Class  Mode
buf25m  3      sf    list
buf50m  3      sf    list
buf100m 3      sf    list
buf400m 3      sf    list
buf800m 3      sf    list
```

I want to use the items (i.e. variable names) of `buffer_vars` into another for loop. However when I print each item of the `buffer_vars` in another for loop, I do get a ton of information on the dataset itself, rather than the variable names of each item. An example of a single item is given:

```
for(j in buffer_vars)
{print(j)}

#gives (one item taken): 

Simple feature collection with 3 features and 0 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 329209.8 ymin: 5713084 xmax: 331157.8 ymax: 5718890
CRS:           +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs
                        geometry
1 POLYGON ((331157.8 5713109,...
2 POLYGON ((329283.5 5718865,...
3 POLYGON ((329259.8 5718627,...
```

However, when I apply a for loop that prints each item in the list `bufs`, results are different:

```
for(i in bufs)
{print(i)}

#gives: 
[1] 25
[1] 50
[1] 100
[1] 400
[1] 800
```

I want to match the output of `buffer_vals` with that of `bufs` so that

```
for(j in buffer_vars)
{print(j)}
#gives: 
[1] buf25m
[1] buf50m
[1] buf100m
[1] buf400m
[1] buf500m
```

The related code:

```
#necessary libraries
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(osmdata)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(utils)
library(rgeos)
library(gstat)

## == create point features dataset == ##

#initialize coordinates
points_long <- c(6.564702, 6.534903, 6.534677)
points_lat <- c(51.54378, 51.59492, 51.59278)

#merge columns to one dataset
points_df <- data.frame(points_long, points_lat)

# convert to spatial dataframe
points_sf <- st_as_sf(points_df, coords = c("points_long", "points_lat"), crs=4326)

#First project data into a planar coordinate system (here UTM zone 32)
utmStr <- "+proj=utm +zone=%d +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80"
crs <- CRS(sprintf(utmStr, 32))
points_sf<-as_Spatial(points_sf)
points_sf_utm <- spTransform(points_sf, crs)
#convert back to sf so that variable can be used as argument in st_buffer
points_sf_utm <- st_as_sf(points_sf_utm)

## == Create for loop that generates x number of buffers around the three defined points.

#initialize buffer parameters
bufs = list(25, 50, 100, 400, 800)
#create empty list to store buffer results into
buffer_vars = list()

# for loop
for(i in bufs){
  buf_i <- st_buffer(points_sf_utm, i) #create buffer around 3 points
  assign(paste("buffer", i, "m", sep = ""), buf_i) #assign buffer to variable name that relates to buffer x
  
  #assign coordinate system to buffer
  buf_i <- st_as_sf(buf_i)
  st_crs(buf_i, crs=crs)  #planar coordinate system (UTM zone 32)

  #store variable in loop to the list that was initialized before the loop
  buffer_vars[[paste("buffer", i, "m", sep = "")]] <- buf_i #store as item in list
  
  #export option
  layer <- paste("buffer", i, "m", sep = "")
  print(layer) #verify
  sf::st_write(buf_i, dsn='C:/Test',layer=layer, driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
  
}

summary(buffer_vars) #examine each item in list
```

Comment: `unlist(bufs)`?

Comment: You want coerce an `"sf"` object to numeric? Check `class(buffer_vars[[1]])`. Somewhat unclear to me.

Comment: I changed the content of my question a bit so that the problem becomes more clear